# MSDE - Connection working in osql, but not DSN

Tags: windows-server-2003, 64-bit, dsn, sql-server

This is on a VPS 64bit machine.

I've installed MSDE fine.  I've created a user.  I can connect via OSQL

osql -Uwwwcubeuser -Psecret

I can run a select * from module

**Problem:  I can't connect via a DSN:**

```
server: localhost
username: wwwcubeuser
password: secret
```

TCP/IP  dynamically determine port

Am getting:  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL SErver Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

There may be a chance that a service that is required is turned off..its a lean install of Win 2003 Datacenter x64

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't enabled tcp/ip in svrnetcn (same directory oas osql).